# Back to back N-MOSFET on low side

Tags: mosfet, batteries, current, mosfet-driver, low-side

I would like to disconnect the current in the system with a battery (using N-MOSFET in a back to back configuration).
I would like the circuit to be on the low side and without a driver.
At this point, the circuit works only with a resistor.
When I add a power supply and the current flows in the other direction, the transistors are turned on all the time. I can't turn off the current flow.
Can such a system be implemented without a driver?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a N-MOS for your bidirectional switch then you need a driver. If you are okay with using P-MOS then you don't need a driver.

[image]

https://www.homemade-circuits.com/bidirectional-switch/

Comment: Okey. But I can only use the P-MOSFET without a driver on the high side. Do I understand well?

Comment: @kamil You understood correctly. This is the benefit of P-MOSFETs. Downside is price and/or high Rdson.